# Comparing UTF8 strings in PHP

Tags: php, string, utf-8, encode

Why does this statement `return` `false`:

```
var_dump( 'çorap' === mb_strtolower('Çorap') ); //bool(false)
```

How can I compare them or convert first to the second?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add an internal encoding on the second parameter of `mb_strotolower()`:

```
var_dump( 'çorap' === mb_strtolower('Çorap', 'UTF-8') );
```